# Python can't find the page on the internet

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to parse the site

```
url = 'https://hh.ru/search/vacancy'
print(url)
hh = requests.get(url)
hh_text = hh.text
print(hh_text)
```

When I run this code, I get this

> ```
> https://hh.ru/search/vacancy
>
> 404 Not Found
>
> <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
> <hr>nginx
> ```

The `print(url)` gives a working link.
This answer appears on all pages of this site.

How to get the site code if there is such a page in the browser, but in Python it cannot find it?

Comment: Are you trying to scrape that site? If so check scrapy: https://scrapy.org/

Comment: The server probably examines your `User-Agent:` string and returns different results when it sees a scraper. `requests` lets you add a header which looks like a regular browser, but sometimes that is not sufficient. For example, the server could also be checking whether your client downloads any images embedded on the page, and determine that you must be a bot if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Site requires a User-Agent header. Therefore:

```
import requests

url = 'https://hh.ru/search/vacancy'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15'}

with requests.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
```